# How can I describe the age difference between myself and my sibling?

Tags: phrase-requests, writing-style

I'm having trouble trying to find a way to convey that I am x years older or younger than one of my siblings.

For example, if I had a sister that's four years older than me, the first thing that comes to mind is:

> Among the visiting family members was my four-years-older sister

Which just seems incorrect. The only other thing I can think of, however, is:

> Among the visiting family members was my sister, older by four years.

... which also sounds strange.

Comment: Why do you need to have it all in one sentence.  Why not say *Among the visiting family members was my older sister.  Those four years were huge when we were kids but ...*"   or whatever.

Comment: @Jim, I'm stuck for space in what I'm writing.

Comment: In that case: "*Family members present included my older sister(30), my younger brother (19) ...*"

Answer (score 4):

If you specifically want to convey this in one sentence, you could try one of:

> - Among the visiting family members was my sister *who is four years my senior*.
> - Among the visiting family members was my sister, *elder than me by four years*.
> - Among the visiting family members was my sister, *older than me by four years*.

As suggested in the comments, you can further improve the brevity quotient of the sentence through the use of parentheses:

> Among the visiting family members was my sister (four years my senior).

Comment: When spatially constrained, any of these suggestions could also be shortened by two words, and using parentheses, i.e.: _my sister (four years my senior)_, or, _my sister (elder by four years)_.

Comment: [elder to me by {X years}](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22elder+to+me+by%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) sounds like "Indian English" to me. I note that in almost every one of the 37 Google Books citations there, the author's name looks "Indian".

Comment: @J.R. Or maybe just *my sister (four years older) and my brother (two years younger)*

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but unless her sister is dead I would say "...who is four years my senior."

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think the concept itself may be "Indian".  Certainly, I would not specify the age of my sister in a letter or conversation, but in other cultures that may be of importance.  I would say "my older sister", but would leave it at that unless I was asked more details.

Comment: @Julia: I'm quite sure that *on average* Indians are more concerned with familial relationships than UK/US speakers, but even at my age I sometimes mention the number of years difference between myself and any of my siblings who crop up in a conversation with someone who doesn't know them at all. I don't really think it's "private" information, and there's always a difference between a brother who's a few years *older*, and, say, a sister who's a decade *younger*.